# Screen Sharing app can’t connect to VNC

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, screen-sharing

I have a VNC server *(a QEMU VM to be exact)* that I want to connect to, but I am experiencing a really strange problem. My server is on [ip]:5905 (or [ip]:5). When I try to connect to this server via VNC Viewer by RealVNC, it connects with absolutely no problems, except the Unencrypted connection warning. When I try to connect to exact same server using the built-in Screen Sharing app, it either tells me that it failed to connect, or it stays in an infinite “Connecting...” loop. What should I do?

*By the way,* I am trying to make a script that opens a connection to this VNC server, so I need arguments for the `open` command too. Thanks.

Comment: What make you think Screen Sharing is compatible with VNC?

Comment: According to [this post from OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/05/vnc-client-mac-os-x-screen-sharing/), it is. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidAnderson screen sharing was working connecting to VNC devices before the upgrade to High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, I was running into this problem trying to install a Kali VM on my M1 Mac. When I tried to connect with `Screen Sharing.app` (with an empty password), it hung at "connecting..." but never worked. I could connect via tiger-vnc, but this wasn't working very well (screen lag, not updating, segfaults).

I eventually figured out that I needed to set a password in my VM configuration. Once a password was set, `Screen Sharing.app` connected right away.

My machine's XML config now contains:

```
<devices>
...
<graphics type='vnc' port='5900' listen='127.0.0.1' passwd='redacted'/>
<video>
            <model type='virtio' vram='32768'/>
</video>
...
</devices>
```

With this configuration, `open "vnc://:redacted@localhost"` from the command line now works as expected (as does <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> in Finder, or `open "vnc://$(whoami):redacted@127.0.0.1:900"`, or several other variations).