# Connect to Screen Sharing (VNC) using Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, remote-desktop, remote-control

I'm trying to connect to a Screen Sharing service using [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/) in Debian, but it doesn't seem to connect.

But now I'm not sure now if this is possible? @[DavidAnderson says](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310625/screen-sharing-app-can-t-connect-to-vnc):

> "What make you think Screen Sharing is compatible with VNC?"

The firewall is currently disabled. The port is definitely open. And Screen Sharing was enabled remotely using [this command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30238/how-to-enable-os-x-screen-sharing-vnc-through-ssh).

```
sudo  /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw mypasswd -restart -agent -privs -all
```

**Is it possible to connect to an Apple Screen Sharing service using Debian or Ubuntu?** If yes, how?

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      System Integrity Protection: Enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to connect to an OS X host using VNC.

It seems, however, that your method of turning it on from the command line doesn't work.

Instead, try

```
sudo defaults write \
/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist \
com.apple.screensharing -dict Disabled -bool false
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist
```

To test it I'd install telnet one the host Mac (you can do it with homebrew - `brew install telnet` and then try `telnet localist 5900` which should get a connection. Then try the same from your Debian box. Once you know you can get a connection from the Debian box try your VNC client.